# Is it possible to migrate asp.net web application to asp.net core mvc,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I want to convert my asp.net web application to asp.net core. It Contains separate class files.Give me solution what i have to do achieve this without rewriting.It is completely c# code.
My asp.net web application contains separate business and datalayer class files. How can i convert without rewriting.

Comment: Cut and paste. You have to rewrite significant code, as ASP.NET Core is a different framework (name similarity doesn't count).

Answer (score 0):

Can copy and paste the class file which matches the same name (or) can check for the website for more reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-3.1